# Remove circles & add colors to elements of Tree

Tags: color, tikz-trees, forest

Question: I am looking for the image added below. And i want to add different colors to every nodes.

This what I have done so far:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \large
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={circle,draw, l sep=10pt}
        [36,black 
        [2]
        [18
        [2] 
        [9
        [3]
        [3]
        ]       
        ]
        ]
        \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this? Just add the `tikz` drawing parameters after the node text (e.g., `draw=red`, `fill=green`, and `text=blue`). You can remove the circles for a given node by adding `draw=none`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \large
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={circle,draw, l sep=10pt}
        [36,draw=none 
        [2,fill=red]
        [18,draw=none
        [2,fill=yellow] 
        [9,draw=none
        [3,fill=green]
        [3,fill=cyan]
        ]       
        ]
        ]
        \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Or

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{forest}
\newcounter{nextcolor}
\xdef\LstColor{{"red","yellow","green","blue","orange","magenta","cyan"}}
\tikzset{fill next color/.style={%
/utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{\LstColor[\number\value{nextcolor}]}
\stepcounter{nextcolor},
fill=\mycolor}}
\begin{document}
    \large
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={l sep=10pt,
        if n children=0{circle,draw,fill next color}{}}
        [36,black 
        [2]
        [18
        [2] 
        [9
        [3]
        [3]
        ]       
        ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to remove circle from 36 , 18 and 9

Comment: @Sandy, sorry! I just saw that part of the question. Updated. You could either remove draw globally and just add it in where you want. Or you can leave it in globally as you have now, and use `draw=none` where you don't want the circles.

Comment: Would you please modified your answer?

Comment: @Sandy. I already did.

Comment: Perhaps the OP wants `for tree={l sep=10pt,
  if n children=0{circle,draw}{}}`

Comment: @marmot, probably. Actually that gives much nicer spacing too.

Comment: @Sandy, if you take marmot's suggestion, you don't need the `draw=none` parameters. The effect is to make the uncircled nodes rectangular, which makes things a bit more compact.

Comment: Please feel free to undo my edit.

Comment: Agree. I am fully satisfied with both answers. I want to ask my last question. Is it possible to increase distance between two nodes?

Comment: @sandy, it's probably best to ask a new question. Others will see it and you are more likely to get good answers quickly. You could play with `inner sep`, `outer sep`, and `s sep` (you can apply to an individual node or include in your `for tree` section) and see if anything gives what you want.